# Intermolecular force vs distance and energy plot

Tags: forces, potential-energy, atoms

I have seen from the graph that Ea is increasing slowly while Fa is increasing really fast. On the other hand Er is increasing faster than Fr. My question is why ? Is there any mathematical idea behind this two plots. Any intuitive idea will be helpful for me.

Extra Details: This is a topic from "Electrical Properties of Material Course". I have tried this one and done some simulation as well but I am not sure about this particular question. So, any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Interatomic attraction and repulsion force and energy]